# How can I use my model properties in a Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this linq query

```
var sales=db.Customers
    .GroupBy
    .Select(c=> new MyModel
     {
        count1=c.where(someCondition).Count(),
        count2=c.where(otherCondition).Count(), 
        finalCount=count2-count1
     });
```

is that possible in linq?
how can I solve such a problem?

Comment: You have to provide a GroupBy-clause.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your problem

Comment: @HimBromBeere he didn't, but it doesn't matter in this question: it's about `Select` clause.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: it matters if he wants to group by multiple properties. It's not clear

Comment: @TimSchmelter I understand it as `how to build some property in object initializer based on others properties`.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: i think i've understood it now, but why he subtracts the count from itself? The result is always 0

Comment: @TimSchmelter again, I think it's just an example, not really very good, but it is as it is. In real world this task is absolutely bizzare, but i just hope that author just didn't think over it enough.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: he has already edited it, now it makes sense. Pseudo code is often not helpful to understand a requirement or an issue

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, like I considered. But now the question is if EF can calculate it itself. I don't think so. But anyway i'm sure that readonly-property is the best choice here. Especially if EF can calculate those two fields but cannot calculare third one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you properly just place your code after property initializer:

```
var sales=db.Customers.GroupBy(...).Select(c => 
{
    var model new MyModel{
        count1=c.Count(),
        count2=c.Count()
    } 
    model.finalCount = model.count1 - model.count2

    return model;
});
```

But in this case i'd like to just create a read-only property on MyModel class:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public int FinalCount => count1 - count2;
}
```

And then initialize only required fields:

```
var sales=db.Customers.GroupBy(...).Select(c => new MyModel
{
   count1=c.Count(),
   count2=c.Count()
});
```

`FinalCount` will be calculated automatically for you.

Comment: helpful and it really helped me

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can use an anonymous block:

```
var sales=db.Customers.GroupBy(...).Select{c=> 
{ 
    int count1 = c.Count(condition1);
    int count2 = c.Count(condition2);

    return new MyModel{
        count1=count1,
        count2=count2,
        finalCount= count2 - count1
    }
});
```

Comment: The `db` tells me the OP is using EF. If that is the case he can't use your select because a lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Answer (score 3):

You can first select  an anonymous type which you project to the second `Select`:

```
var sales = db.Customers
    .GroupBy( ... )
    .Select(g => new
    {
        count1 = g.Where( condition ).Count(),  
        count2 = g.Where( condition ).Count()
    })
    .Select{x => new MyModel
     {
        count1 = x.count1,
        count2 = x.count2, 
        finalCount = x.count2 - x.count1 
     });
```

Comment: EF cannot handle two `Select`'s in chain? Otherwise I don't understand what `AsEnumerable` is doing here.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: everything is translated to SQL, the intialization of the object cannot be translated to sql. The `AsEnumerable` executes the query and does the object initializtaion with `Linq-To-Objects`. So it's good to filter _before_ you use `AsEnumerable`, otherwise you will stream the whole table into memory (or what is the result of the `GroupBy`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I think `AsEnumerable` is not necessary in your second query. EF supports to project queries in a custom class, like `MyModel` also called DTO

Comment: @octavioccl: i'm not sure, i cannot test it. But few days ago i've seen a question here where OP couldn't initialize his objects in the LINQ-To-Entities query. He needed to use `AsEnumerable` before. Unfortunately i can't find the question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter,  when you want to project your query using a entity class from your model, is when you need yo use `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: @octavioccl: maybe it was something different, like using a constructor or something like that which isn't supported. However, good to know that the first approach works I'm not that familiar with Linq-To-Entities. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using `let` clause:

```
var sales=from c in db.Customers
          group c by c.SomeColumn into g
          let Count1= =g.Count(someCondition)
          let Count2=g.Count(otherCondition)
          select new MyModel
                 {
                   count1=Count1,
                   count2=Count2, 
                   finalCount=Count1-Count2
                 };
```

The same using method syntax:

```
var sales=db.Customers
    .GroupBy(c=>c.SomeColumn)
    .Select(g=>new
     {
        Count1=g.Count(someCondition),
        Count2=g.Count(otherCondition)
     })
    .Select(c=> new MyModel
     {
        count1=c.Count1,
        count2=c.Count2, 
        finalCount=c.Count1-c.Count2
     });
```